# Pass function and parameters as parameters to intermediary function which then calls named function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to construct an intermediary function for my WordPress theme that handles all the checking and returning of transients. I want to call the transient function from a template, passing in the transient name and function to call if the transient doesn't exist. Furthermore, I need to pass parameters to use if the function is actually called.

I can't find anything on passing multiple parameters together to use later. For several uses, I can rely on the default parameters of the eventually called functions and so set the third parameter, `$args` to `false`. I looked into using serialize, but that's for one variable at a time, and I need to be able to pass several parameters at once.

Where I call the transient function:

```
$posts = transitize('transientname', 'functionname', "4, false, array($post->projectsiteid)");
```

The transient-checking function:

```
function transitize($transientname, $functionname, $args=false) {
    if (false === ($transient_exists = get_site_transient($transientname))) {
        $functionresult = ($args) ? $functionname($args) : $functionname();
        set_site_transient($transientname, $functionresult, HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
        return $functionresult;
    }
    else {
        return $transient_exists;
    }
}
```

How can I prepare the third parameter, containing 3 parameters for later use, such that the later function call works?

Comment: you can set `$args` as an array and use http://php.net/call_user_func_array to call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the third parameter to an array:

```
$posts = transitize('transientname', 'functionname', array(4, false, array($post->projectsiteid)));
```

Change this line to use `call_user_func_array`:

```
$functionresult = ($args) ? call_user_func_array($functionname, $args) : $functionname();
```